# Domain workstation acting up and I can't track it down

Tags: windows-xp, domain

I have a developer with a Windows XP (SP2) 64 bit machine. If the machine is left on overnight (or any period of time longer than 5-6 hours) it takes 2-3 minutes to open any local drive and his network drives are no longer accessible.  Here's what the system logs report... Any Help

BTW:  The problem just started a week ago and nothing has changed on the domain controller / AD or his machine.

--- ERROR 1
Event Type: Error
Event Source: NETLOGON
Event Category: None
Event ID: 5719
Date:  6/8/2010
Time:  9:17:26 AM
User:  N/A
Computer: BFC1
Description:
This computer was not able to set up a secure session with a domain controller in domain UR due to the following: 
There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.
This may lead to authentication problems. Make sure that this computer is connected to the network. If the problem persists, please contact your domain administrator.

ADDITIONAL INFO 
If this computer is a domain controller for the specified domain, it sets up the secure session to the primary domain controller emulator in the specified domain. Otherwise, this computer sets up the secure session to any domain controller in the specified domain.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
Data:
0000: 5e 00 00 c0               ^..Ą

--- ERROR 2
The machine-default permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{555F3418-D99E-4E51-800A-6E89CFD8B1D7}
 to the user NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE SID (S-1-5-19).  This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

--- ERROR 3
Event Type: Error
Event Source: RemoteAccess
Event Category: None
Event ID: 20106
Date:  6/8/2010
Time:  10:12:18 AM
User:  N/A
Computer: BFC1
Description:
Unable to add the interface {E76F0A78-7A0B-4EBB-A081-BA3BD452FC4C} with the Router Manager for the IP protocol. The following error occurred: Cannot complete this function.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
Data:
0000: eb 03 00 00               ė...

Comment: I always like the "nothings changed" line, guess what somethings changed!

Comment: @tony You're right in that usually, something has changed, but it may be a partial hardware fault causing the problem, so they may not have made any changes or updates, but the hardware itself could have changed.  It's easy to blame problems on someone changing something, but sometimes things do change on their own too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've double and triple checked the IP configuration of the machine (especially the IP, subnet, and DNS settings), it might be a NIC Driver issue. Does the machine have the latest drivers?